# Trying to use a gradient bottom border. Works well on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: css, forms, mobile, border, gradient

I ve been messing around for some time now. Im trying to give a gradient bottom border to my textarea input field in form. It does work well on desktop, also on inspector when i try mobile devices. But in reality on mobile devices i always get either borders all around (not same size tho - or a weird shade (looks like somekind of box shadow inverted on border top).

Last thing i ve tried was changing the textarea field to a regular div, but then I changed my mind. If its the only way to work around this then maybe, but I dont like mixing up stuff too much :/

```css
textarea {
    background-color: #f2f2f3;
    height: 100px;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to left,
            purple 1%,
            hotpink 50%,
            hotpink 100%) 0 0 90% 0/0 0 1px 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f3;
    padding-left: 10px;
    line-height: 1.15;
}
```

```html
<form class="formulier" action="php/mail.php" method="POST">

  <h1 class="contact">CONTACT</h1>
  <p>Laat hier je gegevens achter en wij zullen zo snel mogelijk contact opnemen!</p>
  <input id="voornaam" placeholder="Voornaam*" type="text" name="name" required>

  <input id="achternaam" placeholder="Achternaam*" type="text" name="name" required>

  <input id="telefoon" placeholder="Telefoon*" type="tel" name="phone" required>

  <input id="email" placeholder="Email*" type="email" name="email" required>


  <textarea id="tekstvak" placeholder="Opmerking" name="message"></textarea>


  <input id="verzenden" type="submit" value="Verzenden">
  <!--<input class="leegmaken" type="reset" value="Clear">-->
</form>
```

Comment: Some screenshots will help to understand the issue

Comment: I got a solution thx, was on this website, but must have missed it!